# How to add a string to both sides of a found substring

Tags: php, regex

I have an input string:

```
10 birds have found 5 pears and 6 snakes.
```

**How can I put html tags around substrings found with a regular expression?**

For instance, I want all numbers to be bold, like this:

```
 <b>10</b> birds have found <b>5</b> pears and <b>6</b> snakes.
```

Comment: That's not difficult, have you tried anything?

Comment: When you're asking for specific help with debugging something, you need to show what you've tried.

Comment: I have tried, still don't which PHP functions to use. To find the substring is not hard, to put string in front and behind is harder. I tried combination of preg_mach and str_pad() but it wasnt the best solution.

Comment: preg_replace_callback()

Comment: @LarsStegelitz: this function is not needed `preg_replace` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$str = '10 birds have found 5 pears and 6 snakes.';
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
```

Output:

```
<b>10</b> birds have found <b>5</b> pears and <b>6</b> snakes.
```

Comment: For god sake. I forgot I can use the found string as variable. That was it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex you can do that:

```
$items = explode(' ', $text);
$result = array_reduce($items, function ($c, $i) {
    return ($c ? $c . ' ' : $c)
         . (is_numeric($i) ? '<b>' . $i . '</b>' : $i);
});
```

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski: Because this way, when it's possible to use it, is 2x faster for this kind of string length.